# Facebook deep linking not working

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking

I used to implement deep linking of Facebook in iOS device from the following link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/app-links

And, it used to work around 2 weeks ago, but it is not working now when I tried to implement it again.

Is Facebook depreciated this feature since it has the new feature of app link?

All answers are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Facing the same behaviour...

Comment: As I have found it is a need to implement App-link, instead of a simple Deep-linking.